# Starting today, no internet for 2 MacBook Pro with BigSur

Tags: network, wifi, big-sur

I am having issues connecting to the Internet using two 15'' MacBook Pros (Mid 2014 and 2017), both running Big Sur. Until today, I had no connection issues with them. A few more details:

- On both machines, I can ping `www.google.com` but I cannot access the same page from a browser.
- I have the same result with Chrome, Firefox and Safari.
- I am trying to connect the machines to my home wifi, which has two channels (standard and 5G). The issue is not solved if I change the network.
- If I run Wireless Diagnostics, I get the message "your wi-fi connection appears to be working as expected".
- I have the same issues if I try to connect the two MacBook Pros to my phone's hotspot.
- None of the issues listed above occur when I use my 13'' Mac running Sierra.

The only hypothesis I have is that the issue is somehow related to the OS. Do you think that makes sense? Do you have suggestions on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with curl ? Ex : curl -o xx.html https://www.google.com    Or : curl -o xx2.html http://www.google.com

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I tried and I got the error `Couldn't connect to server`.

Comment: Have you got a firewall or proxy on your network or on your computers ?